# Azure AD Group does not show group owners under owners tab

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have an Azure AD Group of `source = Windows Server AD Group`.

On the `Overview` tab of the group shows the owners listed, however it does not show any Owners listed on `Owners` tab. Why is such behavior?  What is wrong ?

[image]

Comment: Could you include how you added owner to AD group in Windows Server?

Comment: I am not sure this is done by separate team. All I am aware is that AD is synced with on-premise active directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In `Overview` tab of the group, what you are seeing is the **Group
> description** not the owners list. While creating the AD group, they
> added group description like that.

I created one AD group in my Windows Server with similar **Group description** like below:

[image]

Now, I used **Microsoft Azure AD Connect** to sync this group to Azure AD like this:

[image]

After syncing this to Azure AD, I got same results as you with **group description** as owners list in `Overview` tab as below:

[image]

> Note that, you **cannot sync** on-premises group owners of AD security groups to Azure AD.

**Reference:**
[Sync On Prem AD group owners to Azure AD - Microsoft Q&A by **Andy David - MVP**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1020823/sync-on-prem-ad-group-owners-to-azure-ad)